# Windows Media Player Audio Codec

Tags: video, audio, windows-media-player, codec

I can't play 3GPP2Video files with the audio working. As in the the video works, but I can't hear anything. I can play the same file with quicktime, and the audio and video both work. Where can I find this plugin or what should I do to enable playback of these filetypes in windows media player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These codecs has support for 3GPP2

FFDShow - [web](http://www.free-codecs.com/FFDShow_download.htm)